# How to split a text file in linux from the bottom of the file to the top based on a given pattern

Tags: linux, text, split, pattern-matching

How to split (it doesn't matter what command) a text file in Linux from the bottom of the file to the top based on a given pattern.

If I have the file:

```
111
aaa
222
aaa
333
aaa
```

The output should be

```
1st file
    333
    aaa

2nd file
    222
    aaa

3rd file
    111
    aaa
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can try using wc,head and tail command to write a script maybe?

Comment: What is the criterion? Always 2 lines? Always one line before aaa? From 333 descending to 111 with one additional lines/all lines after the last number? Is it always 6 lines in total?

Comment: Everything what is above the pattern until the next pattern.

Comment: What is the pattern? Repeated ciphers? 3 repeated ciphers? Numbers? Everything which is not 'aaa'? You gave an example, not a pattern.

Comment: Understood. aaa is the pattern. between the pattern could be more than 2 lines. Some times 1 sometimes 10. To be more precisely, I would like a command similar to: csplit file  /aaa/ {*} but to read the file from the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the file with `tac` and then run it through `csplit`.  The -k option means that you don't need to know the number of splits in advance.

tac file | csplit -s -k - "/aaa/+1" "{99}"